# Try to create array string for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a little problem, i try to create array of string to insert into mongodb.
The string is in this form:

```
"[\"clock_POSTMAN_90\",\"container_customer\",\"container_ssv\",\"weather_POSTMANT\",\"slideshow_general_uuu\",\"languagechanger\",\"appselector\"]"
```

Is a serializer string, and i want to convert or to something to change into this  form:`["clock_POSTMAN_90","container_customer","container_ssv","weather_POSTMANT","slideshow_general_uuu","languagechanger","appselector"]`

I tried multiple option, parse to JArray, substrings, trim,substring but is ineffective. 
Any sugestion?

Comment: What is your issue? because the strings are the same, try printing the string and you will see. And if you want an array, just do `string.Replace("[", "").Replace("]","").Split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Both the string are same \" is treated as " for more Detail on Escape Sequence go to the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)